# No logro seleccionar el txt (type num) de un div. en la console

Tags: javascript

**El div es el siguiente:**

```
<div class="pt" id="pt">565656</div>
```

**Y yo en mi JS he escrito:**

```
var num0 = document.getElementById('pt').innerText;

console.log(num0);
```

**pero me tira error**...

> Uncaught  TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null at
>   evaluacion.js:1

**Ahora si le quito el 'innerText' me responde:** null.

**¿¿Que puedo hacer??**

Quiero tener el txt de ese div (565656) en la consola para poder hacer luego otras operaciones dentro de la página con cajeo de puntos.

Comment: Tu archivo JS lo estas importando antes de finalizar el body?

Answer (score 3):

Ese error se debe a que no está encontrando el elemento en el DOM. Asegurate que tu archivo javascript lo estes importando antes de cerrar el body de la sigueinte manera:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="pt" id="pt">565656</div>

    <script src="./js/evaluacion.js">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ITS WORK!!!!! muuuuchas gracias renzo!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ocupa `innerHTML`

Ejemplo

```js
var elemento = document.getElementById('pt').innerHTML;
console.log(elemento)
```

```html
<div class="pt" id="pt">565656</div>
```

Comment: me sigue tirando el mismo error
por las dudas les mando imágenes para que puedan ver

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxmvi.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP1WG.png

Comment: pero porque marcas -1 la respuesta, verifica el import de tu archivo javascript debe ser al final en el body

Comment: imagino que el script esta importado en el html donde esta el div...

Answer (score 0):

Ese error se refiere a que `document.getElementById('pt')` es `null` no ha encontrado ningun elemento dado que tenia un espacio en el `div` que abre la etiqueta, haciendo que no sea un elemento del `DOM`. Por otra parte el resto del codigo esta bien.

```js
var num0 = document.getElementById('pt').innerText;

console.log(num0);
```

```html
<div class="pt" id="pt">565656</div>
```

Comment: el error del div fue cuando lo publique en este página.
como nunca habia publicado aqui, hice eso mal

Comment: Si ejecutas el codigo veras que todo corre perfecto,